# Show Typo3 FlexForm checkbox items inline

Tags: typo3

Would it be possible to show the checkboxes inline, so behind each other with a FlexForm? I'm now using the following code, but this shows every setting in a vertical list.

```
                <settings.ownchoice_for_sale>                   
                    <TCEforms>
                        <label>For sale</label>
                        <config>
                            <type>check</type>
                        </config>
                    </TCEforms>
                </settings.ownchoice_for_sale>
                <settings.ownchoice_reserved>                   
                    <TCEforms>
                        <label>Reserved</label>
                        <config>
                            <type>check</type>
                        </config>
                    </TCEforms>
                </settings.ownchoice_reserved>
```

Comment: So you mean if you check 'ownchoice_for_sale' the form gets reloaded and 'ownchoice_reserved' is shown? `inline` stands for "Inline- Relation- Record- Editing (IRRE)" see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Inline/Index.html

Comment: No I mean that the option are shown inline in the form. So behind each other instead above each other.

Comment: okay I've answered your question. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexforms does not support such `palette` functionality like TCA offers.

You can use a `multiple value selector` to offer all available options in a single field instead of using `checkboxes` (see: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#columns-select-examples-multiple).

**An example of this in your case:**

```
<settings.ownchoice>
  <TCEforms>
    <label>Own Choice</label>
    <config>
      <type>select</type>
      <items>
        <numIndex index="0">
          <numIndex index="0">For Sale</numIndex>
          <numIndex index="1">for_sale</numIndex>
        </numIndex>
        <numIndex index="1">
          <numIndex index="0">Reserved</numIndex>
          <numIndex index="1">for_sale</numIndex>
        </numIndex>
      </items>
      <size>10</size>
      <minitems>0</minitems>
      <maxitems>100</maxitems>
      <suppress_icons>1</suppress_icons>
    </config>
  </TCEforms>
</settings.ownchoice>
```

And in your controller:

```
$options = ($this->settings['ownchoice'] ? \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $this->settings['ownchoice']) : array());

if (in_array('for_sale', $options)) {
    // option 'for_sale' is selected
}
```

Comment: very sad that the result is a string...so we can not nicely deal direct with it in view... BUT thanks for this solution! Much nicer then making 3 separate checkboxes